# Doorkeeper Authentication from Rails GraphQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, doorkeeper

I'm trying to provide a "sign in" for GraphQL queries in a Rails (4.2.10) app. The "user" and "password" fields are being passed in. In my mutations.rb, I have:

```
field :signin, !types.Boolean do
  argument :user, !types.String
  argument :password, !types.String
  resolve -> (_, args, _) {
     #what here?
  }
end
```

Some documentation (out of date?) suggests:

```
Doorkeeper.authenticate args
```

This gets me a "undefined method `authorization'" in my tests, which I assume means I'm missing a callback somewhere. I've dug down but not been able to figure out what I need.

I've also tried

```
Doorkeeper::Application.by_uid_and_secret args.user, args.password
```

and this seems to return nil.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to build a `signin` mutation to take the OAuth credentials. This seems like a bad idea. OAuth is a well-established set of processes that API clients know how to follow. The OAuth Client Credentials flow process already includes a way to pass credentials to the OAuth server and get back an access token.

That access token should be used (as part of the value in an `Authorization` header for example) to authenticate subsequent GraphQL API calls.

So instead of implementing a mutation that replaces the OAuth flow, add an OAuth implementation to your API consumer, and enable the Client Credentials flow in Doorkeeper.